# What's the difference between these two new syntaxes?

Tags: c++, new-operator

What's the difference between these two when we swap them? It compiles for me.

```c++
int main()
{
    X p;
    X* ptr = new (&p) X;

    X* ptr = new X (&p);
}
```

Comment: just because something compiles doesn't mean it'll actually run, or work as expected.

Comment: They aren't new.. The first one is placement new and allocates memory at the address of P. The second one creates a new instance of X on the heap and calls its constructor with &ptr as a parameter.. I think.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: *allocates memory at the address of P* --- not quite. It creates an object of type `X` over the variable `p`. It does *not* allocate memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
X* ptr = new (&p) X;
```

uses *placement new* to construct a new object of type `X` at the location pointed at by `&p`. This causes undefined behavior in this particular context because `p` already has an object at its position (unless X is trivially copyable and destructible). It then returns a pointer to the object, which will be at the same address as `p`, so when we're done `p` and `ptr` will point to the same object.

The line

```
X* ptr = new X (&ptr);
```

constructs a new object of type `X` at a location that's dynamically allocated, passing into the constructor the value of `&ptr`. This only works if `X` has a constructor that takes in an `X*`. The expression then returns a pointer to the new object, which cannot be the same as `&p`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "unless X is trivially copyable and assignable" -> trivially destructible.

Comment: Are you sure about the UB claim? Wouldn't the original p just not be destructed (and thus "only" leak)? The placement-new object would overwrite the original object attributes and get destructed when p leaves scope.

Comment: @TilmanVogel To the best of my knowledge, constructing a new object on top of an existing one causes undefined behavior unless the object is trivially destructible. Placement new won't end the lifetime of the original object by itself, but if you manually called the constructor you should be able to make this work.